# MS Access combo box list order different from row source

Tags: combobox, sql-order-by, ms-access-2016

My DB is tracks equipment being used at events.

- [Asset] table tracks all assets (AssetId, AssetName, Make, Model...)
- [Event] table tracks all events (EventId, EventName, Type, StartDate, ...)
- [AssetEvent] table tracks which asset was used at which event

"frmUsage" is unbound, and has an Event drop down (working perfectly fine), and an "Asset" dropdown.  I want the Asset dropdown to display the Assets ordered by AssetName, but to bound the AssetId value (to use in other parts of the form).

Asset's SQL is:

```
SELECT A.AssetId, A.AssetName FROM tbl_Asset AS A INNER JOIN tbl_AssetEvent 
AS AE ON A.AssetId = AE.AssetId WHERE (((AE.EventId) Like 
Nz(Forms!frmUsage.EventId,"*"))) GROUP BY A.AssetId, A.AssetName ORDER BY A.AssetName;
```

Behaviour:

- Expected:  When Event has been selected in the form, it should only show Assets associated to the form.  Actual behaviour is as expected.
- Expected:  Dropdown values should show AssetName, and bind AssetId.  Actual behaviour is as expected.
- Expected:  Dropdown values should be ordered by AssetName.  Actual behaviour NOT as expected.  Values are are ordered by AssetId.

How do I fix this?

Details:
The combo box is configured with:

- Column Count: 2
- Column width: "0cm;2.5cm".
- Row Source Type: Table/Query
- Bound Column: 1
- Limit to List: Yes

Comment: Did you use wizard or insert query yourself? Run the query manually and confirm. SQL output matches your expectations

Comment: I manually inserted the SQL, and yes, I've already confirmed that the SQL, when run manually, shows the output in the correct order.

Comment: `NAME` is a reserved word so that could be causing weird things to happen. I'd first try renaming your fieldname and if you're absolutely fixed on using it at least wrap it in square brackets as in `[NAME]` - all reerved words are listed at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/286335/list-of-reserved-words-in-access-2002-and-in-later-versions-of-access

Comment: Yes you're right.  The column names I have are actually "AssetId" and "AssetName", so it's not a reserved word issue.

Comment: Well maybe update your question with the actual facts - and perhaps add your SQL

Comment: Updated the question with details.  Note:  even when I remove WHERE clause, the dropdown values are still ordered by AssetId instead of AssetName

Comment: Get rid of the Group By on `A.AssetId`

Comment: I need `A.AssetId` in the output for other parts of the form to use.  I can't have it without putting it in the Group By.  There are duplicate assets in `tbl_AssetEvents`.  I tried adding the DISTINCT predicate and removing Group By entirely, but that didn't work.

Comment: Added an answer to see if I understand what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need the `AssetID` grouping but the query is working other than that, 
then you can add it into a separate query inside and `Order By` outside that one.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT A.AssetId, A.AssetName FROM tbl_Asset AS A INNER JOIN tbl_AssetEvent 
AS AE ON A.AssetId = AE.AssetId WHERE (((AE.EventId) Like 
Nz(Forms!frmUsage.EventId,"*"))) GROUP BY A.AssetId, A.AssetName)
ORDER BY A.AssetName;
```

Comment: You must have the OrderBy  property set to Asset ID in the combox box properties or you're resetting the control's RecordSource property in code when the Form loads

Comment: The control's **RecordSource property** was being set on the Got Focus event.  I commented this out and it works well now!!  Thanks!!

Comment: Excellent - thanks for coming back to confirm and mark as an answer